# get previously submitted `post` data after switching to another razor view asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm submitting data of an advertisement to the particular controller action method of it. Then I need to redirect user to the payment page to carry out the payment details. Then I need to save the advertisement details. But after i switch to the payments page previously submitted advertisement details are lost and returns null when trying to save it to database

Posting `Business` details and redirecting to payments page as below

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" formaction="@Url.Action("Index", "Paypal")" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then user will be redirect to the payments page

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and if payment is done should save the previously submitted data to db

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" formaction="@Url.Action("PaymentWithCreditCard", "Paypal")" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The PaymentWithCreditCard is as below

```
public ActionResult PaymentWithCreditCard([Bind(Include = "ID,ItemName,ItemPrice,ItemQuantity,cvv,month,year,fname,lname,cardnumber,cardtype,fee,Subtotal,Total,Shipping,Tax")]
    Paymentinfo paymentinfo, [Bind(Include = "ID,Title,Address,Category,Description,Latitude,Longitute,Owner")] Business business)
    {

        @*Some code here...*@

        if (!(business == null))
        {
            business.Owner = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Businesses.Add(business);
                db.SaveChanges();//This will save null data to database since these will get null values
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Businesses");
            }

            return View(business);
        }

        return View("Success");
    }
```

How can I figure this out..?

Comment: You need to persist the data before you do the redirect and read it back (using the Id or PK column value) in the next action method. You can store it in a table or store it in a cache or store it in TempData etc.

Comment: i was trying to use temp data. anyway was able use them. cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a model and store the data there and later call it onto another view

Comment: What in the world does this have to do with the question (and OP already has a model!!)